# How do you return a 2d array in C++?

Tags: c++

How do I return a 2d array in C++?

For example, I have the following method in java:

```
public static int[][] getFreeCellList(int[][] grid) {
    // Determine the number of free cells
    int numberOfFreeCells = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) 
      for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
        if (grid[i][j] == 0)
          numberOfFreeCells++;

    // Store free cell positions into freeCellList
    int[][] freeCellList = new int[numberOfFreeCells][2];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
      for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
        if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
          freeCellList[count][0] = i;
          freeCellList[count++][1] = j;
        }
    return freeCellList;
  }
```

I'm trying to replicate this in C++.  Normally, I would pass in the 2d array i wanted to return as reference parameter of the method in C++.

However, as you see in the method above the size of the array being returned isn't known until run-time.

So, in this case I'm guessing I need to actually return a 2d array, right?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `vector` of a `vector` as well.

```
typedef vector<vector<int> > array2d_t;

array2d_t etFreeCellList(array2d_t grid) {
    // ...

    array2d_t freeCellList;

    // Determine the number of free cells
    int numberOfFreeCells = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) 
       for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
          if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
      freeCellList[count][0] = i;
      freeCellList[count++][1] = j;
    }
    return freeCellList; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner arrays seem to be fixed to size of 2. You could therefor use a vector of `array`

```
static std::vector< array<int, 2> > getFreeCellList(int grid[][9]) {
    // Determine the number of free cells
    int numberOfFreeCells = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) 
      for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
        if (grid[i][j] == 0)
          numberOfFreeCells++;

    // Store free cell positions into freeCellList
    std::vector< array<int, 2> > freeCellList(numberOfFreeCells);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
      for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
        if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
          freeCellList[count][0] = i;
          freeCellList[count++][1] = j;
        }
    return freeCellList;
}
```

Usage is like

```
int x[9][9] = { ... };
std::vector< array<int, 2> > pa = getFreeCellList(x);
```

No need for manual memory management since you use `std::vector`. `array` is in boost, but you can quickly write a similar class manually

```
template<typename E, int N>
struct array {
  E &operator[](int I) { return data[I]; }
  E data[N];
};
```

The data member is an array of `N` elements of type `E`.

Alternatively, you can write this using low-level 2d arrays. Since the inner dimension is fixed in your code, you can actually allocate a real, native 2d array instead of a complicated 1d array of pointers to separate buffers:

```
static identity<int[2]>::type *getFreeCellList(int grid[][9]) {
    // Determine the number of free cells
    int numberOfFreeCells = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) 
      for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
        if (grid[i][j] == 0)
          numberOfFreeCells++;

    // Store free cell positions into freeCellList
    int (*freeCellList)[2] = new int[numberOfFreeCells][2];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
      for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
        if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
          freeCellList[count][0] = i;
          freeCellList[count++][1] = j;
        }
    return freeCellList;
}
```

Now you can use it like

```
int x[9][9] = { ... };

// equivalent: identity<int[2]>::type *pa = ...;
int (*pa)[2] = getFreeCellList(x);
// ...
delete[] pa;
```

Notice the use of `identity` (from `boost` or see below) to simplify the syntax. You would need to write the following otherwise

```
static int (*getFreeCellList(int grid[][9]))[2] {
  // ...
}
```

---

```
// identity implementation (for working around the evil C++ syntax)
template<typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a struct and then return the struct. Otherwise C++ doesn't allow returning arrays. You can also return a pointer to the first element (of flat 1D array or fully dynamic 2D array).

Comment: @cobbal: Pointers are not the same thing as arrays. They are very different types. You may be confused because arrays implicitly convert into pointers (to their first element) very easily. Given char array[10]; and char* ptr = array; sizeof(array) == 10 and sizeof(ptr) == 8 on my system. The array variable contains storage for 10 chars, while the ptr variable contains storage for a memory address.

Comment: they are the same thing actually, but edit clarifies enough that I withdraw my objection

Comment: Another source of confusion is that in function prototypes, if given array types, one dimension always converts into pointer automatically (for performance reasons, I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an arbitrary-sized 2d array, just as you can't pass an arbitrary-sized 2d array as a parameter.

C++ arrays are *horrible* compared to Java arrays. Don't touch them! Use a `vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A construct like

```
int[][]
```

in C and C++ only exists for static data, such as

```
int[][] =
{
    {1, 2},
    {0, 1}
};
```

where the compiler can determine the size of the elements at compile time. If you know the size of the inner arrays at compile time - or if you can just can make them fix, then use a typedef such as:

```
typedef int[16] IntArr16;
```

Then your function can return a array of this type

```
IntArr16* getFreeCellList(...).
```

This all is plain C. Other possibilities are (as explained by dirkgently) to return stl containers.

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a C-style solution than a C++-style solution, but you can always return a structure like

```
struct {
    int   dimension_one;
    int   dimension_two;
    void* pArray;
} return_type_t;
```

Allocate your 2D array dynamically, store the two array dimensions and a pointer to the allocated memory in the structure, and pass that back to the caller.